# Woocommerce Sendinblue email changed download url of product

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, sendinblue, wp-mail

My product is downloadable. I use WP Mail SMTP plugin and Sendinblue to send Woocommerce emails. After payment email is sent with the wrong product download url.

For example:

**Woocommerce sends** download link http://example.com/?download_file=105&order=wc_order... And it works well.

**Client receives** email with link https://efibdia.r.bh.d.sendibt3.com/tr/cl/OkC... And no file can be downloaded through it.

Anyone faced this issue?